# Install CPAN Modules without messing up the system Perl installation

Tags: linux, filesystems, perl

I have heard that it is best to not install modules from CPAN where your system's version of Perl is.  I know how to install modules using the command line, I was just wondering if there is a way to keep CPAN separate from the system's core Perl.

Should I:

*Download the source and make a directory specifically for these modules?*

Anybody have any other ideas or implementations they have used successfully?

Comment: @KarthikT I thought I would get opinions on both sites.  Should I close this one?

Comment: I am not sure of the rules in such cases, you can leave it as such for now

Comment: Isn't it an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928005/install-cpan-modules-without-messing-up-the-system-perl-installation ?

Comment: I thought I would get opinions on both sites. Please close or delete appropriately. I didn't know the rules for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPAN is always separate from core – notice how `/usr/lib/perl5` has subdirectories `core_perl`, `vendor_perl` (CPAN modules packaged by the distro) and `site_perl` (modules installed locally).

Both *ExtUtils::MakeMaker* and *Module::Build* default to installing everything to the "site" directory; this also applies to everything you install using the `cpan` or `cpanm` commands. If you use your Linux distro's packages, they go to the "vendor" path.

You can specify a different installation location (for example, to keep all CPAN modules in your home directlry) using:

```
dir=~/perl5

export PERL5LIB="${dir}"
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE='${dir}'"
export PERL_MB_OPT="--install-base '${dir}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The risk you take when you install in the system directories is that every system related Perl script will use those modules. If one of the modules is a newer and incompatible version of a module the system uses, then you won't be happy.

The recommended way to install in a private directory is to use local::lib. See the bootstrapping technique: https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib

Once you set up local::lib you can use any of the standard CPAN clients to install modules.